# XQUERY: reutrn values from different tags using xquery

Tags: xml, xquery

I´m starting using xquery and I want to know how to get the values from 2 different type of tags.
for example:

xml

```
<elementType>value</elementType>
<otherElementType>value</elementType>
<elementType>value</elementType>
<elementType>value</elementType>
```

xquery

```
"for $b in $doc//elementType return stringg($b)" 
"for $b in $doc//otherElementType return stringg($b)"
```

I want this but only using one query, how can that be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Use what is possibly the shortest expression**:

```
//*[self::elementType or self::otherElementType]/string()
```

Comment: Thank you so much Dimitre! I really apreciate your help

Comment: , do you know how can I concat text to those values I receive? for example for elementType I need to get all elements values as: elementType/string()+"type: elementType" and for the other: otherElementType/string()+"type: otherElementType"

Comment: @user1642468, You are welcome. As for your other comment, I don't understand what result exactly you want to get?

Comment: I need to get the values of the tags (you already help me with that) and with those values I need to add some text to the values, the text depends on the element type, so in the previous example I will have to add a string for elementType and another string for otherEmlementType

Comment: @user1642468: What text must be added? As you see exchanging code within comments isnt convenient at all. I recommend that you ask a new, separate question.